# How to install which programs requires "sudo" in virtualenv?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

I'm trying to install [kivy](http://kivy.org), in the [docs](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-ubuntu.html) it says:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-pygame python-opengl \
  python-gst0.10 python-enchant gstreamer0.10-plugins-good cython python-dev \
  build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev
$ sudo easy_install kivy
```

But I don't want to use `sudo` I like to keep my projects organized in virtualenv, so how install the requirements without using `sudo`. `apt-get install` won't work unless i use `sudo`. and i can't find the requirements in `pip`. Lets say i want to install `easy_install` in virtualenv for example, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can get around installing kivy's dependent packages without sudo/root access.

Once you have them installed, follow steps outlined in Andrew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002598/754042).

Answer (score 1):

when you use virtualenv and start it running, you can use the easy_install / pip that is installed there.  that doesn't require sudo because it installs directly to virtualenv.

in other words - it just works.  have you tried it?

there's a simple example here http://www.arthurkoziel.com/2008/10/22/working-virtualenv/

- `sudo easy_install virtualenv`  (the last sudo you need)
- `virtualenv kivydir`
- `source kivydir/bin/activate`
- `easy_install kivy` (installs to kivydir)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work as kivy has other dependent packages, so an attempt to run easy_install kivy within virtualenv will fail.

Comment: oh, ok.  thanks, now i see what the question was asking.  eh - you could probably build them all by hand with custom paths, but life is too short :o(  i'll leave this up since it's referenced in another answer.